# How to create an array/dataframe populated by 1 or 0 based on whether time is within a range?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, time

Basically, I have a *dataframe* which has 2 columns, both of which are hours:

```
    0    1
 +-----+----+    
0|  11 | 12 |
 +-----+----+
1|   3 | 4  |
 +-----+----+
2|  11 | 12 |
 +-----+----+
3|   6 |  7 |
 +-----+----+
4|  16 | 16 |

     etc...
```

This has a few thousand rows. I want to make another dataframe which has column headers '1' to '24' (based on the hours of a 24 hour period) and for each row of the dataframe above displays 1 if the hour time is within that range (inclusive) and 0 if it is outside.

So for example the second row of the above dataframe would be something like:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 ......24
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0 ......0
```

And I want to do the same for each row of the first dataframe and append to the new 24 hour data frame.

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help! Happy to walk through further if it doesn't make sense! Also am new to posting on here so not sure exactly how to get the data to paste over in a sensible way.

Comment: What are your hour parameters and why are there so many columns in your second DataFrame? If your first DataFrame has 2 columns, why would the second not have 2 columns if it is based on a conditional test of where the hours in the first DataFrame are?

Comment: I'm trying to test how many times each hour appears in the ranges of the first data frame for occupancy (each row is data for whether an item is present in an area for a certain hour). I thought the easiest way to do this would be populate a dataframe with 1 for hours present and 0 for hours outside the range. Then eventually sum up for each of the individual 24 hours to get a total for each hour.

Comment: Dude instead of going for sum by taking the number of hours appearing just subtract df[0] from df[1] i.e `df[1] - df[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([dict.fromkeys(range(a, b + 1), 1) for a, b in zip(df[0], df[1])])
        .reindex(columns=range(1, 25), fill_value=0)
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int))

print (df)
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

[5 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, so for example how would this code look if my first dataframe was called "OccupancyTimes_df"? Getting some errors at the moment so probably just doing something silly!

Comment: Change `zip(df[0], df[1])` to  `zip(OccupancyTimes_df[0], OccupancyTimes_df[1])`, if string s columns `zip(OccupancyTimes_df['0'], OccupancyTimes_df['1'])`

Comment: And for sum use `df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can compare and multiply the values by creating a dataframe i.e

```
temp = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(1,25)],index = df.index,)

begin = (temp.values>=df['0'].values[:,None]).astype(int)
end = (temp.values<=df['1'].values[:,None]).astype(int)


pd.DataFrame(begin*end,columns=np.arange(1,25))

    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks, how would this code look if my first dataframe was called "OccupancyTimes_df"? Getting errors at the moment so probably just doing something silly!

Comment: replace `df['0']` with `OccupancyTimes_df[0]` and `df['1']` with `OccupancyTimes_df[1]`

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([[11, 12],[3,   4],[11,  12],[6,  7],[16,  16]], columns=[0,1])
print("df= \n ",df)

dg=pd.DataFrame(columns=np.arange(1,26))
for i in df.index:
    for j in [0,1]:
        dg.loc[i,df.iloc[i,j]]=1
print("dg= \n", dg.fillna(0))

df= 
      0   1
0  11  12
1   3   4
2  11  12
3   6   7
4  16  16
dg= 
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```